# What part needs replacing on this Whirlpool Gas Dryer

Tags: repair, dryer, appliances, natural-gas

This old dryer still works great, but, makes a noise that is a combination of freight train derailing and thunder.  See video:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/DUB8zAg45vE5a1XE7

[image: Whirlpool Gas Dryer LG6801XPN0 Label]

Pressing on the rotating drum quiets things down, perhaps realigning whatever is worn out.  What might that be, and can it be replaced?  And was it indeed made in 1954 (LG6801XPN0 M54103383)?

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer bc I'm not sure, but I had a washer that went to the spin cycle, if I guests over when doing laundry they'd ask: "what is that sound?"  I said that's just my 747 washing machine getting ready for take off.   Ended up replacing rather than repairing.   In your case, it's probably bearings that are completely worn out. I'd love to see you keeping that antique going if you can find the parts. I hate today's throwaway culture.

Comment: Of course this is just a guess. The most likely cause is worn drum support wheels or center support bearing if it has one.

Comment: _If_ you can find a place that still sells parts that will fit a dryer built in 1994. Oh... **1954**? Good luck! Honestly, it is probably bearings or drum support wheels, possibly both, maybe the drive belt, too. You'd have to get measurements of the different parts then contact the online sellers to see if they'll give you dimensions of the parts they're selling and find something that matches. Once you've got the proper parts, it'll be a matter of kit-bashing things together. There's roughly zero chance of finding parts _designed_ for this model any more.

Comment: Would try to find a local machinist.  They will be able to measure the parts and know where to find replacements that will fit.  As others have mention, trying to order by part number might be very hard.

Comment: Oh, I'd also suggest looking at the drum itself. Particularly where it touches the various bearings/rollers that allow it to spin. It may well be worn down after... _takes off shoes_ 67 years of use. You may need to measure the wear and upsize bearings/rollers to accommodate the shrinkage in the drum itself.